# Excel Create a rule that copies a text value from a cell with several criteria between tabs in document

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I seem to have hit a wall with this.

I have multiple tabs within my spreadsheet for different clients and orders between each. I have a summary sheet and I am trying to automatically pull the data through to that and avoid manual input as much as possible.

I have a formula that works for creating a sum of the values between sheets that may help give you some background:
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$F7&"'"&"!B$7:B$28"),Figures!A7,INDIRECT("'"&$F7&"'"&"!G$7:G$28"))

F7 is the name of the tab the data is held (i use a drop box with clients names to populate the value)

B7:B28 is where the data to match can be found on F7 tab name

A7 is the order number that I want to match within B7:B28 on the F7 tab name

G7:G28 is the sum of the order values

so rather than show a numerical value from column G on F7 tab I want to show the order name held in column C on the F7 tab if the order number in A7 matches a value in column B on the F7 tab.

I have tried a number of different variations unsuccessfully, please help!

cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Could you share what you have tried? Maybe we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this using VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH as shown below.

```
=VLOOKUP(Figures!A7,INDIRECT($F7&"!$B$7:$C$28"),2,FALSE)

=INDEX(INDIRECT($F7&"!$C$7:$C$28"),MATCH(Figures!A7,INDIRECT($F7&"!$B$7:$B$28"),0))
```

This is assuming that the order number A7 is unique. That is not clear since you are using SUMIFS so you may need to convert these to array formulas which you can read about [here](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/).

Comment: Thank you! The Order Number is unique so the solution works perfect.